# Self reference in GXT Propery access

Tags: java, gwt, gxt

I am reading this [documentation about GXT PropertyAccess](http://docs.sencha.com/gxt-guides/3/data/propertyaccess/PropertyAccess.html).

I am creating a `Grid<Stock>` which contains a custom column. This column needs a `ValueProvider` which provides the whole `Stock` :

```
public class MyCustomCol<T> extends ColumnConfig<T, Stock> {

  public MyCustomColl(ValueProvider<? super T, Stock> valueProvider, String header) {
    ...
  }
}
```

How can I express it in a GXT `ProperyAccess` ?

```
public interface StockPropertyAccess extends PropertyAccess<Stock>{

  @Editor.Path("") //Which Path should I use here? I unsuccessfully tried "" 
  ValueProvider<Stock, Stock> zis();

  ValueProvider<Stock, Integer> id();
  ValueProvider<Stock, String> name();
  ...
}
```

Comment: Give us the model you're trying to display (Stock) and try to explain what value you want your ValueProvider to provide. Then I should be able to help you. Also is the normal that StockPropertyAccess has no `ModelKeyProvider` in your example?

Comment: @RadASM I took a simple example because my *real* model contains useless information for StackOverflow. My need is to display an information which is actually composed of several fields of the object. I can bypass the problem by creating an additional getter which does the work but this seems not to be the best solution. Suppose I want to display "{id}-{name}" in a column : how would you do it??

Comment: Okay I see exactly what you want to do as I already tried the same. Unfortunately I couldn't figure out how to do so. According to what I read the only way to do it is to create a class that implements ValueProvider interface and create your how ValueProvider to use. The only thing I think you can do using @Path annotation is `@Path("composedObject.objectValue...)`

Comment: Just to know you should rather have `ValueProvider<Stock,String>` than `ValueProvider<Stock,Stock>` if I understand well what you want to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of trying to make a generated `ValueProvider` type for this, there is one that already exists. But first: what is a ValueProvider that you need one that talks about the whole object?

The idea is that it provides a sort of simple 'reflection' on properties of an object, but without actual reflection (since GWT doesn't support it). These are read/write by default, allowing both a `setValue` and a `getValue` method to not only read the value out, but optionally write something back again.

This `ValueProvider` interface can easily be implemented by hand as well - there is no need to start with the PropertyAccess to do it for you if it doesnt know how to solve your problem. In the case of talking about an object itself, you can just return the original object. Here is a (partially implemented) idea of how that should look:

```
public class IdentityValueProvider<T> implements ValueProvider<T, T> {
    public T getObject(T object) {
        return object;
    }
    public void setValue(T object, T value) {
        //can't do anything to set object to a new value, ignore, or throw exception
    }
    //...
}
```

This class actually exists in GXT, and is called IdentityValueProvider, since it returns the same object as it is given (it is an "identity function"). You can make your own if you want to customize, otherwise, just pass it in as-is:

```
ColumnConfig<Stock, Stock> column = 
        new ColumnConfig<Stock, Stock>(new IdentityValueProvider<Stock>());
```

---

In one of your comments, you further clarify that you need to print out `id + "-" + name` from the full object, so ideally you want to just return that string? This might look like this:

```
public class IdAndNameStringProvider implements ValueProvider<Stock, String> {
    public String getValue(Stock object) {
        return object.getId() + "-" + object.getName();
    }
    //...
}
```